# Xbox says I have to sign in on Xbox Live but I don't have or want an Xbox Live account

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

My Xbox 360 says `Your console can't conncect to Xbox Live. Do you want to exit the session and test connections?`. I don't have Xbox Live and don't want it. I just want to sign in on my profile and play games. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 7):

Create a local profile. I have couple of them, for players that I play on split screen. Such account isn't sync with Live.

You can create such accunt via accounts from screen menu.